# 500 Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file on Multicategories Component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I have a site that I upgraded from Joomla 2.5 to 3.10.12. The previous site is using [Multicategories v1.0.4](http://milkdev.com/en/blog/43-multicategories-component-for-joomla25-version-104-released) component, it doesn't work on Joomla 3.10 and there is no update from the Author so I tried to upgrade the component manually.

I got it to work until the Control Panel tab: http://www.domain.local/administrator/index.php?option=com_multicategories
[image]

But when I click on Categories, I get the error below: http://www.domain.local/administrator/index.php?option=com_multicategories&view=categories&extension=com_multicategories

`500 Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file`
[image]

File directory: `administrator/components/com _multicategories`

[image]

I tried searching for solutions online but couldn't find much and it does work on me.

Any advice on how I can fix this or what is causing the error? thanks

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.